# Get height of all child ListViews

Tags: xaml, listview, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

So I have a **ScrollView** with a **StackPanel**. Inside the StackPanel I have **three ListViews** with different `List<object>-sources`.

What I want to achieve is to disable scrolling on the ListViews and only scroll all of them in the same ScrollView.

I get something that scrolls a little bit okey when i hardcode the height of the scrollview, but if I don't do that it only snaps back to start after I release the finger. How can I achieve to get the height?

Current XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewHeaderDisableScroll" TargetType="ListView">
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
            </Style>

        <Page
        x:Class="TestApp.SecondaryView.PatientDetailView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ViewModels="using:TestApp.ViewModel"    
        mc:Ignorable="d">

        <Page.DataContext>
            <ViewModels:PatientDetailViewModel />
        </Page.DataContext>
        <Grid Background="White">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                /* Menu-Grid*/



                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" IsVerticalRailEnabled="True" Height="800">
                    <StackPanel Name="StackPanel_Lists">
                        <ListView Style="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderDisableScroll}" ItemsSource="{Binding DummyProblems}" Background="White">
                            <ListView.Header>
                            <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderStackPanel}">
                                <TextBlock Text="HEADER 1" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Play" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListView.Header>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate  x:DataType="ViewModels:PatientDetailViewModel">
                                    <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="DimGray" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="{Binding Note}"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="DimGray" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="{Binding Fo}"></TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                        <ListView Style="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderDisableScroll}" ItemsSource="{Binding DummyMeasures}"  Background="White">
                        <ListView.Header>
                            <StackPanel Background="DarkGray" Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Padding="8,8,8,8">
                                <TextBlock Text="HEADER 2" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Play" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListView.Header>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate  x:DataType="ViewModels:PatientDetailViewModel">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="DimGray" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="{Binding Description}"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="DimGray" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="{Binding Note}"></TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                        <ListView Style="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderDisableScroll}" ItemsSource="{Binding DummyGoals}"  Background="White">
                        <ListView.Header>
                            <StackPanel Background="DarkGray" Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Padding="8,8,8,8">
                                <TextBlock Text="HEADER 3" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Play" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListView.Header>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate  x:DataType="ViewModels:PatientDetailViewModel">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="DimGray" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="{Binding Description}"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="DimGray" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="{Binding Fo}"></TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
                </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found this:

The StackPanel outside og everything did ruin everything. I changed it to Grid and made the ScrollView *. Now everything works